# GoTo in IntelliJ IDEA does not work

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm developing some js projects (react.js) in IntelliJ IDEA, have many modules linked with export/import, all placed in a tree of folders that is open in my project

anyway, none of IntelliJ's GoTo features work...

can you tell me how to configure quick navigation through function declarations between modules and modules?

Comment: You can use Ctrl+left mouse click as an easy alternative. :)

Comment: 'cannot find declaration to go to' - even if a function is declared IN THE SAME MODULE !!!

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is a sign that the caches/indexes for the project are corrupt. Go to *File > Invalidate Caches / Restart* and select "Invalidate and Restart". After Restarting, wait for IDEA to re-index the project, and then give it a try, Note that invalidating caches will delete your local history (in the event you use that).

Comment: tried that - no luck, same result, 'cannot find declaration to go to'

Comment: This worked for me. As you said,I lost the local history. But i did not find another way to recreate the index.